# How to access built-in completion sources?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to get access for built-in completion sources like keywords in the current buffer or `omnicompletion`? I am trying to make my own completion manager based on `completefunc`. I know there is `\k` character class and I can simply search through the whole buffer but it is such an overhead to deal with on each key presses.

If not, do you know the way to copy all keywords into the list? Keep in mind, I need cursor ordinary atom `\%#` so the family of `match` functions is unacceptable.

Comment: This question is *way* too open-ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently there's no such function available in Vim. My [CompleteHelper plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914) has generic functions to extract arbitrary patterns from buffers; I use it to implement several custom completions. Additionally, I've written emulations of the local keyword and tag completions in [this (unpublished) library](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-BuiltInCompletes). Feel free to reuse or derive your own code from it!

Comment: I have already forgotten about this question. Yes, unfortunately there is no such feature. Keywords are just all I need. Nevertheless, thank you for sharing your code.